# Redirect permanent redirected too many times apache

Tags: php, apache2

I'm using apache Redirect permanent configuration to redirect http traffic to https however I'm getting myexample.com redirected you too many times. Below is my virtual host file config:

```
<VirtualHost *:7777>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myexample.com/
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web/
        Redirect permanent / https://myexample.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myexample.com/
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web/
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header always unset Server
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        <Directory />
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/web/>
                LimitRequestBody 512000
                Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
         SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        TraceEnable off

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Kindly assist.

Comment: The problem may be that your servername is wrong... it shouldn't contain `/` at the end... maybe Apache can't find a proper virtualhost and takes first configuration form the file.

Comment: If you have a Load Balancer, check if it forwards the connection on :443, and it forwards the ssl status.

Comment: I don't have a load balancer. if i comment out Redirect permanent, apache serves both http and https but I want it to serve https only.